# Apache Tika Server: get macros from office documents?

Tags: python, apache-tika

I'm using Apache Tika as service to analyze Office documents in Python, like so:

```
url = 'http://{0}:{1}/rmeta/xml'
url = url.format(self._host, self._port)
res = requests.put(url, data=dat).json()
```

I'd like to extract the content of macros from the documents if the document contains macro, but can't figure out how to do it. Apache Tika documentation is not that good. Is there any header or something I need to use to make Tika server return macro content as well as the content of the document?

Comment: Ask for the embedded contents separately from the metadata? (The Java API for Apache Tika lets you do lots of things at once, but the REST interface to the server generally needs you to ask for just one thing at a time)

Comment: @Gagravarr, I thought that 'rmeta' endpoint should return all metadata recursively, so if the document has embedded content it should extract it, parse and return the metadata. So how should I do it in general? Firstly I request 'rmeta' to get the metadata for the root document, then how do I ask if the document has other document embedded in it? How do I ask to parse the embedded data if it exists?

Comment: @Gagravarr the docs for 'rmeta' endpoint says that it "Returns a JSONified list of Metadata objects for the container document and all embedded documents". I think the problem here is that by default Tika is not extracting the content of Office Document macros. So I should somehow pass the option to parse macro to OfficeParserConfig, but I can't figure out how I should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood the problem is that Tika by default doesn't extract macros from Office Documents. In order to make it do exactly that I had to make a custom config file for Tika, enabling extractMacros property to both Microsoft Office parsers implemented in Tika (I don't know if they use POI or something). Here is an example how to do it: https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-parsers/src/test/resources/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/tika-config-macros.xml